# QSqlQuery last not working

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite

I'm trying to get the size of an executed query in SQLite but when I use last and try to use last its always false
 
Here is the code I'm trying to execute

```
void createDB() {
  QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE","CREATE_CON");

  db.setDatabaseName("C:/Desktop/TestDb.db3");
  db.open();

  QSqlQuery q(db);
  q.exec("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Test(testCol TEXT PRIMARY KEY);");
}

int entries() {
  QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE","SELECT_CON");

  db.setDatabaseName("C:/Desktop/TestDb.db3");
  db.open();

  QSqlQuery q(db);
  q.exec("SELECT * FROM Test;");

  if(q.last() == false) {
    qDebug()<<q.lastError().text();
    qDebug()<<db.lastError().text();
  }
  return q.at()+1;
}
```

The error text I get is empty so I don't know what I'm doing wrong.
 
I can create the database just fine so my database instance is working as it should.
 
 
Operating system: Windows 10
 
I'm using: Qt 5.10.1
 
Compilator: MinGW

Comment: How do you create the table?

Comment: have you opened the database? your code is very ambiguous, please provide a [mcve]

Comment: I just tried it and it works correctly, if not provide a [mcve] your question would fall on the off-topic *"why is not this code working?"*

Comment: what time do you call createDB()?

Comment: @eyllanesc I call the createDB() function when I start the program the when I press a button the entries() function is called.

Comment: q.exec("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Test(testCol TEXT PRIMARY KEY);");?? what is `q`?

Comment: @eyllanesc its the QSqlQuery instance forgot to put it in the function example above have fixed the code example above

Comment: please put a code that can be executed, that's the definition of a [mcve], to me that type of errors gives me doubt where the error is.

Comment: @eyllanesc the code above can be executed forgot the variable when writing the code above. I have run the program still get the same error. I have opened the database with DB browser for SQLite and checked that the database was created the right way it was.

Comment: As you can see, the behavior is correct, if there is no data in the table, there is no last element, therefore last will be false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behavior is correct, if your table is empty there will not be a last element so `last()` will be false.

I will take this question to show you that you must validate all possible errors. A program can sometimes work but the duty of a good programmer is to prevent it from always working.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QSqlDatabase>
#include <QSqlQuery>
#include <QSqlError>

#include <QDebug>
#include <QPushButton>

static bool createDB() {
    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE","CREATE_CON");

    db.setDatabaseName("TestDb.db3");
    if(!db.open()){
        qDebug()<<db.lastError().text();
        return false;
    }

    QSqlQuery q(db);
    if(!q.exec("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Test(testCol TEXT PRIMARY KEY);")){
        qDebug()<<q.lastError().text();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

static int entries() {
    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE","SELECT_CON");

    db.setDatabaseName("TestDb.db3");
    if(!db.open()){
        qDebug()<< db.lastError().text();
        return -1;
    }

    QSqlQuery q(db);
    if(!q.exec("SELECT * FROM Test;")){
        qDebug()<<q.lastError().text();
        return -2;
    }

    if(!q.last()) {
        return 0;
    }
    qDebug()<<"not empty";
    return q.at()+1;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    if(!createDB()){
        return -1;
    }
    QPushButton button("call entries");
    QObject::connect(&button, &QPushButton::clicked, [&](){
        qDebug()<<entries();
    });
    button.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of :

```
q.exec("SELECT * FROM Test;");

if(q.last() == false) {
    qDebug()<<q.lastError().text();
    qDebug()<<db.lastError().text();
}
```

You should do:

```
if(!q.exec("SELECT * FROM Test;")) {
    qDebug()<<q.lastError().text();
}
```

And if you want to know the size of the query, why don't you store it in a `QString`, and call whenever you want [QString::length()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#length)?